# Android - Change color of multiple choice listview background

Tags: java, android, listview, colors, onitemclicklistener

I have a multiple choice ListView which defaults as having a white background but when selected, the background of the item changes to blue (defined here by a hex code).

```
mItemState = new boolean[list.length];
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListOfMajors.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);
mylist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mItemState[position] = !mItemState[position];
        if (mItemState[position]){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33b5e5"));                                       
        }else{
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);                       
        }

    }

});
```

Right now, everything seems to be working fine. However, if I select the very first element, the very last element also changes background color (it does not get ticked however). Also, if I choose the very last element, the same thing happens to the very first element. What seem to be the reason that this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Well you must be familiar with ListView recycling mechanism and convertView model. The last elements view is composed using first elements view as convertView . Consider this  blog http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to fix this?

Comment: You can subclass `ArrayAdapter` class override `getView(...)` and not use convertView , but that's a very bad idea.

Comment: How exactly would I use convertView in my case?

Comment: in the link above that i considered there's an example of `getView(....)` method you can remove ` if (convertView == null) ..` condition and remove `ViewHolder` class.